# Flex Air HTML (Listening for javascript alert and bypass it)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, action

I am getting a document java script object from htmlloader like following below.

```
var document = htmlloader.window.document; 
var btn:Object = document.getElementById('btn_id');
```

Then I have a button using getElementById like this.That btn has some validation and I am calling it automatically with some data and dispatch the event like this.

```
var evt:Object = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, htmlLoader.window, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
btn.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Sometime an error occured and Java Script alert comes and halt the execution and when I click on that alert Ok button it executes normally.
I just need to bypass that alert or listen for that alert so I can show my own Flex related Popup Window or something like that.
Any body have any ideas...?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would try and debug the code to see why an error is being thrown? Are you passing the correct data types into your initMouseEvent method?

Otherwise:

Try adding a `try` `catch` block when dispatching the event and then showing your flex popup in the error handling.

```
var evt:Object = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, htmlLoader.window, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
try{
   btn.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
catch(e){
   //handle error - show flex alert
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_try_catch.asp

Comment: This is not an error which I have to catch - This is something a validation error message coming from a site as Java Script Alert which I want to disable and dont know how to do that in Flex AIR